# How to validate code that read/write to hardware memory mapped registers (mmio) with frama-c Eva plugin or WP-RTE?

Tags: frama-c

The closest answer I found maybe related to `-absolute-valid-range` for the Eva plugin but is that it?  Do I have to come up with read/write ACSL predicates to do dummy read/write?

Sample code:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

#define BASE_ADDR 0x0e000000
#define BASE_LIMIT 0x0e001000
#define TEST_REG 0x10

/*@ requires BASE_ADDR <= addr < BASE_LIMIT;
  @ assigns \nothing;
 */
static inline uint32_t mmio_read32(volatile uintptr_t addr)
{
    volatile uint32_t *ptr = (volatile uint32_t *)addr;
    return *ptr;
}
/*@
  @ requires 0 <= offset <= 0x1000;
  @ assigns \nothing;
 */
static inline uint32_t read32(uintptr_t offset)
{
    return mmio_read32((uintptr_t)BASE_ADDR + offset);
}

void main(){
    uint32_t test;
    test = read32(TEST_REG);
    return;
}
```

Frama-c command and output:

```
[frama -absolute-valid-range 0x0e000000-0x0e001000 -wp mmio2.c
[kernel] Parsing mmio2.c (with preprocessing)
[wp] Warning: Missing RTE guards
[wp] 6 goals scheduled
[wp] [Alt-Ergo] Goal typed_read32_call_mmio_read32_pre : Unknown (Qed:4ms) (51ms)
[wp] Proved goals:    5 / 6
   Qed:             5
   Alt-Ergo:        0  (unknown: 1)][1]
```

How to discharge goal "typed_read32_call_mmio_read32_pre" or is this expected?

Comment: Strictly speaking, `-absolute-valid-range` is an option of Frama-C's kernel, even though WP is unable to take advantage of this information as far as I know. That said, there are several possible workarounds and the most appropriate course of action is heavily dependent on your code and the properties you want to prove about it: you need to be more specific in your question (i.e. provide us with a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order for us to provide meaningful answers.

Comment: Virgile I updated the question to include the mcve.  What I also found the unkown status could be related to volatile variable in the code.  Do you know if WP plugin can handle volatile variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the proof fails is related to two independent issues, but none of them is related to using absolute addresses.

First, as the argument of `mmio_read32` is marked as `volatile`, WP consider that its value can be anything. In particular, none of the hypotheses that are made on `offset` are known to hold when evaluating `addr`. You can see that in the GUI by looking at the generated goal (go in the WP Goals tab at the bottom and double click in the `Script` colon and the line of the failed proof attempt):

```
Goal Instance of 'Pre-condition'
 (call 'mmio_read32'):
Assume {
  Type: is_uint32(offset_0).
  (* Pre-condition *)
  Have: (0 <= offset_0) /\ (offset_0 <= 4095).
}
Prove: (234881024 <= w) /\ (w_1 <= 234885119).
```

`w` and `w_1` correspond to two read accesses to the volatile content of `addr`. I'm not sure if you really intended the `addr` parameter to be `volatile` (as opposed to a non-`volatile` pointer to a `volatile` location), as this would require a pretty weird execution environment.

Assuming that the `volatile` qualifier should not present in the declaration of `addr`, a remaining issue is that the constraint on `offset` in `read32` is too weak: it should read `offset < 0x1000` with a strict inequality (or the precondition of `mmio_read32` be made non-strict, but again this would be quite uncommon).

Regarding the initial question about physical adressing and volatile, in ACSL (see section 2.12.1 of [the manual](http://frama-c.com/download/acsl.pdf)), you have a specific `volatile` clause that allows you to specify (C, usually ghost) functions to represent read and write accesses to `volatile` locations. Unfortunately, support for these clauses is currently only accessible through a non-publicly distributed plug-in.

I'm afraid that if you want to use WP on code with physical adressing, you need indeed to use an encoding (e.g. with a ghost array of appropriate size), and/or model volatile accesses with appropriate functions.

Comment: Virgile,  Thank you for a very thorough answer.  Yes if I removed `volatile` and change the precondition for `read32` to strict inequality then WP can prove all the goals fine.

Comment: @ratt You're welcome. Don't hesitate [to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if this indeed fixes your problem.